# Making a form appear for only one specific post

Tags: javascript, show-hide

On my site, you're able to make a post. The form to comment on a post is hidden, and should appear when you click the "Reply" button. The problem is, with a normal JS hide/show script, it hides/shows ALL of the forms, and I'm unsure of how to make it specific to only one form. Could anyone help?

Comment: You have to tell us what you've tried so far. Otherwise, hire a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the form in a div, give the div a specific id, then use GetElementById.... BAM.

Comment: Why not just give the form a specific ID instead?

Answer (score 0):

Easy to solve with the answers already posted, but if you dont give as some code to play with it, and see what you are doing, if difficult to guess what you have in your code.

In //guessing mode ON//...

**CSS**

```
form{display:none}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="one">contact</form>
<form id="two">reply</form>
<form id="tree">buy</form>

<div id="reply_button" onclick="document.getElementById('two').style.display='block'">reply</div>
```